# Databases for running statistical tests

Tags: python, database

I am trying to apply knowledge i learnt during statistics courses to real world datasets.

I am looking for some real database/tables. Would be helpful if the link to page added as well  . Format is not a constraint - i use python and i can well convert to sqlite .

One example would be [one medium sized table] of for identifying country for given ip address : http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/node/view/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since your profile says you're from India, I thought some Indian Government statistics would help, so a quick google search yields this site:

http://mospi.nic.in/dwh/index.htm

Click on 'Tables', and you'll have a list of more data/tables than you could possibly need.

...these files all seem to be in Microsoft XLS format, but another quick google search yields a free converter: http://download.cnet.com/XLS-Converter/3000-2077_4-10401513.html
...or you could run a python program, xlrd ( http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd ) and read the files directly.

Comment: @Anil:  if you think the answer is adequate, you should accept it.